# Apply a function to both sides of an equality in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm in Coq trying to prove that

```
Theorem evenb_n__oddb_Sn : ∀n : nat,
  evenb n = negb (evenb (S n)).
```

I'm using induction on `n`. The base case is trivial, so I'm at the inductive case and my goal looks like:

```
k : nat
IHk : evenb k = negb (evenb (S k))
============================
 evenb (S k) = negb (evenb (S (S k)))
```

Now of course there's a fundamental axiom of functions that asserts

```
a = b -> f a = f b
```

For all functions `f : A -> B`. So I could apply `negb` to both sides, which would give me

```
k : nat
IHk : evenb k = negb (evenb (S k))
============================
 negb (evenb (S k)) = negb (negb (evenb (S (S k))))
```

Which would let me use my inductive hypothesis from right to left, the negations on the right would cancel each other out, and the defintion of `evenb` would complete the proof.

Now, there might be a better way to prove this particular theorem (edit: there is, I did it another way), but as this in general seems like a useful thing to do, what's the way to modify an equality goal in Coq by applying a function to both sides?

*Note: I realize that this wouldn't work for any arbitrary function: for example, you could use it to prove that `-1 = 1` by applying `abs` to both sides. However, it holds for any injective function (one for which `f a = f b -> a = b`), which `negb` is. Perhaps a better question to ask, then, is given a function which operates on a proposition (for example, `negb x = negb y -> x = y`), how can I use that function to modify the current goal?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you just want the `apply` tactic. If you have a lemma `negb_inj : forall b c, negb b = negb c -> b = c`, doing `apply negb_inj` on your goal would give you exactly that.