# Apply a function to both sides of equality in a Coq hypothesis

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The question I have is very similar to the one presented in the link below, but on a hypothesis instead of a goal.

[Apply a function to both sides of an equality in Coq?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27069454/apply-a-function-to-both-sides-of-an-equality-in-coq?rq=1)

Say I have the following definition :

```
Definition make_couple (a:nat) (b:nat) := (a, b).
```

And the following lemma to prove :

```
a, b : nat
H : (a, b) = make_couple a b
-------------------------------
(some goal to prove)
```

I would like to generate the following hypothesis:

```
new_H : fst (a, b) = fst (make_couple a b)
```

One way is to write explicitly an assert, then use eapply f_equal :

```
assert (fst (a, b) = fst (make_couple a b)). eapply f_equal; eauto.
```

But I would like to avoid, if possible, to write explicitly the assert. I would like to have some tactic or equivalent that would work like this :

```
apply_in_hypo fst H as new_H
```

Is there anything in Coq that would come close to that?

Thanks for the answers.

Comment: This is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36996408/2747511).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `f_equal` lemma to do that.

```
About f_equal.
```

> ```
> f_equal : forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (x y : A), x = y -> f x = f y
>
> Arguments A, B, x, y are implicit
> Argument scopes are [type_scope type_scope function_scope _ _ _]
> f_equal is transparent
> Expands to: Constant Coq.Init.Logic.f_equal
> ```

Here is how you can apply it to a hypothesis:

```
Goal forall a b : nat, (a, b) = (a, b) -> True.
  intros a b H.
  apply (f_equal fst) in H.
```

The above snippet can be rewritten in a more concise manner using [intro-patterns](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.intros):

```
  Restart.
  intros a b H%(f_equal fst).
Abort.
```

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was looking for